# Returning an array of two fields in Yii2 afterFind()

Tags: php, yii2

In a model, I have two fields that are arrays of values,  those are `implode`d inside a model on `beforeSave()` and saved into database as strings (this is working fine).

Now, I need to know, how can I retrieve these two fields back into an array on `afterFind()` so the fields can be populated inside a form.

I should probably note that every form operation is done via RESTful API, and frontend is in AngularJS.

```
    public $array_1 = [];
    public $array_2 = [];

    public function beforeSave($insert)
        {
            $this->array_1 = implode(',', $this->array_1);
            $this->array_2 = implode(',', $this->array_2);
        }
```

When I want to do an explode by the same principle, I get error that argument 2 in `explode` is expecting string and get's an array. I'm assuming that it's because of the array parameters declaration at the top of the file.

I'm total Yii2 newbie, so please be gentle. :)

Comment: display code where you use explode function.

Comment: Maybe your `array_1` is already array when finding.

Comment: Yasin Patel , thas is exactly what I need, because when I reverse above function and use these fields in afterFind, I'm manipulating same parameters and it doesn't work. Maybe my question is not formulated right, I tried my best to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your piece of code, I suggest doing the following staff.

Using afterFind() and beforeSave()

```
//public $array_1 = []; ( those are redundant )
//public $array_2 = []; ( those are redundant )
public function afterFind()
{
  $this->array_1 = explode(',', $this->array_1);
  $this->array_2 = explode(',', $this->array_2);
}
```

---

Sometimes I do as follows:

For example, instead of array_1, array_2 I have one "column", which I like to be able to get as array or raw value (from DB)

```
public function getColumnArray()
{
  return explode(',', $this->column)
}

public function setColumnArray($value)
{
  $this->column = implode(',', $value);
}
```

So when I write $model->columnArray, it will give me array value of $model->column. And if I want raw string, then just $model->column

---

I hope these are what you need

Comment: I understand that, but If I do it this way, I get an error "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given".

Comment: @TenderloinSky, oh I get it. See my updated answer please

Comment: greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A simple is manage you data  using afterFind (in model)  .. so each time you retrieve a model you can perform wath you need

```
public function afterFind()
{
  $this->performYourManiplation();
}
```